# create probability function of my dataset

Tags: data-visualization, density-function

[image]

I want to create a probability density function of my dataset. I follow the advice of a specialist to visualize my dataset...Which is distribution fits my dataset visualization? Thank you!!!
Your advice is essential!

---

[image]

Here is the Kernel density function.

Here is my Matlab coding:

---

x= [7.998118274731637, 9.37056278501453, 10.862858709115953, 12.830882909700314, 14.996370576370452, 17.95125482369249, 21.050007345521607, 25.034296923707835, 28.355892510753424, 31.830495159438755, 34.07133829876933, 38.05071430556109, 41.0610324344455, 41.0610324344455]
n=length(x)
[f,xi,bw] = ksdensity(x,'Bandwidth',11.9486);
figure
plot(xi,f,'--');

---

11.9486 is the std of my dataset

Do you think that my dataset is too short?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to create this function? What is the question you are trying to answer with that?

Comment: I want to find the probability of a telecom parameter to be less than a particular value...I had put a different image but it does not appear..The Kernel density isn't correct...It appears the previous image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset has only $n = 14$ observations, of which (the highest) two are the same. So, you are not likely to get a useful kernel density estimator (KDE).

Even so, I guess you ought to get *something.*
For the original data, I get the same sample standard deviation as you
do. Rounded to two decimal places, your dataset
can be summarized in R as follows:

```
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   8.00   13.37   23.04   23.89   33.51   41.06 
length(y);  length(unique(y);  sd(y)
[1] 14        # sample size
[1] 13        # there is one tie
[1] 11.94825  # sample standard deviation
```

The default KDE of R is shown along with a histogram
of the (rounded) data below:

```
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 rug(y)  # tick marks on axis
 plot(density(y), lw3=3, col="orange")
```

[image]

With a tiny change in the largest observation
to avoid ties, a Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit
test finds your sample
to be consistent with sampling from the uniform distribution on $(0, 50).$

```
y1 = y
y1[14] = 41.07
ks.test(y1, punif, 0, 50)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  y1
D = 0.1786, p-value = 0.6994
 alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

I will not try to de-bug your Matlab session, but
two possibilities come to mind. (1) Matlab will
not find a KDE for such a small dataset. (2) Matlab
does find a KDE, but you did not do what is necessary to plot it, or to superimpose it on your histogram.

*Note:* Given a fair chance, the default KDE from R often gives good results.
Here is output for a sample of size $1000$ from
the distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=4, \mathrm{rate} = .05).$ The population density is
shown as the dotted curve.

```
set.seed(2022)
w = rgamma(1000, 4, .05)
hist(w, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.013), col="skyblue2")
 lines(density(w), lwd=3, col="orange")
 curve(dgamma(x,4,.05), add=T, lwd=3,
      lty="dotted", col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: You visualize two kernel density functions. The first is from my dataset and the second is using distribution gamma. What is the best in my case?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. // The first uses _your data_ and casts doubt whether so little data can lead to a useful KDE. The second (in the end note) has _nothing to do with your data_ and shows that in appropriate circumstances KDE can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant of Sigmoid function to fit your distribution, as:
[image: Sigmoid function]

Although, you need to adjust the output of the fitting function according to PDF range, as:
[image: Range function]

I have tried a simple python code to verify it, you can try it and tune some of its variables to achieve desired output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.zeros(60)
data[0:40] = 6
data[40:60] = 2

x = np.arange(0,60)
c2 = 39.5                    # function decreasing point
c1 = 8                      # strictness constant

datapdf = data/np.sum(data) # Normalizing distribution to get PDF

ffunc = abs(1.0 - 1/(1+np.exp(-c1*(x-c2))))                                                         # variant of sigmoid function
PDFfunc = (ffunc - min(ffunc))/(max(ffunc)-min(ffunc))*(max(datapdf)-min(datapdf))+min(datapdf)     # To keep same probability range as PDF

# Visualizing PDF and fitting function
plt.plot(datapdf)
plt.plot(PDFfunc, '--')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.legend(('PDF','Fitting function'))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1+len(datapdf), 10))
plt.show()
```

[image: PDF and fitting function]

However, I would advise you to go further than fitting a function, as for the most practical probabilistic models, the exact inference is intractable*. You can try Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) and/or Monte Carlo Sampling.

*Christopher M. Bishop, and Nasser M. Nasrabadi. Pattern recognition and machine learning, Springer Science+Business Media,New York, USA, 2006; pp. 523–556.

Comment: Do you want to see my results?